# Centering DIV in header

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

So I am trying to put logo on my wordpress site at the very top of the header above menus, in the middle. I've set it to top but cannot set it to center horizontal. I've tried align:center, display:block, margin:0, auto but all of those lines were completely ignored by the site I am not sure why.

How can I center div with an image in it to the center horizontal in header?
Here is some code that i think should be relevant if there is anything else that might be relevant please tell me, I'll post it.

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
  <!-- Logo -->
  <div calss="logo-wrapper">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="http://www.precom.com.pl">
        <div class="logo-wrapper" style="width:80px;left:30px;top:0px;">
          <img src="http://www.precom.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/cropped-g3025.png" alt="Precom - Kominki i Wentylacje">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Logo / End -->
</div>
```

Comment: You have a typo in `<div calss="logo-wrapper">`. Should be `<div class="logo-wrapper">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the block you're trying to center has the follow:

```
.logo-wrapper{
position:relative;
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
float:none;
text-align:center;
    }
```

If the element has absolute positioning it will more than likely ignore the margins.

Comment: ok, i've put your code in custom.css with .col-md-3 in the beginning and then deleted the left/width and now it's how it's supposed to be - in the middle. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

This issue crops up on more more than a number of times a week. I know the frustration!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:
`text-align: center;`

You can use also this:

```
.logo-wrapper {
   text-align: center;
}
```

This willl center the div.

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
  <!-- Logo -->
  <div calss="logo-wrapper" style="background-color:#000;width:500px;">
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="http://www.precom.com.pl">
        <div class="logo-wrapper" style="text-align: center;">
          <img src="http://www.precom.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/cropped-g3025.png" alt="Precom - Kominki i Wentylacje">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Logo / End -->
</div>
```

Comment: used your code but it didn't move at all, maybe there's a some part of the code that blocks all those centers :/

Answer (score 0):

You have specified `top`, `left`, etc. in your `<div>`. Please remove them. Instead, give a `margin: auto;` for them.

```
<div class="logo-wrapper" style="width:80px; margin:auto;">
    <img src="http://www.precom.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/cropped-g3025.png" alt="Precom - Kominki i Wentylacje">
</div>
```

Comment: I removed top and left in <div> but even though i gave it margin:auto it didn't move at all.  `<div class="logo-wrapper" style="width:80px;margin:0px;"><img src="http://www.precom.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/cropped-g3025.png" alt="Precom - Kominki i Wentylacje"></div> `

Answer (score 0):

You have some html mistakes (div calss logo-wrapper )...So i rebuild your html

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
   <div class="logo">
     <div class="logo-wrapper" style="width: 160px; margin: 0 auto;"><a href="http://www.precom.com.pl"><img src="http://www.precom.com.pl/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/cropped-g3025.png" alt="Precom - Kominki i Wentylacje">  </a>
     </div>                           
   </div>  
</div>
```